# Ubuntu 22.04 configure local IP via netplan (systemd-networkd)

Tags: networking, netplan, systemd-networkd

I have a server installed with Ubuntu 22.04, with two physical network interfaces - eno1 and eno2, and I configure these network interfaces with **netplan** (which uses systemd-networkd). eno1 is with link detected, and it is configured with dhcp, and eno2 is without link detected (which is OK), and it is configured with a local IP.

**The problem:** eno2 do not get a local IP address via netplan.

The files:

```
cat /etc/netplan/50-eno1.yaml 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
-----------------------------
cat /etc/netplan/60-eno2.yaml 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno2:
      addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
-----------------------------
cat /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eno1.network 
[Match]
Name=eno1

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=100
UseMTU=true
-----------------------------
cat /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eno2.network 
[Match]
Name=eno2

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=192.168.0.10/24
```

ifconfig:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 aa::aaa:aaa:aaaa:aaaa  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1197608  bytes 75258702 (75.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 84445  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8120  bytes 1741477 (1.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xbbbbbb-bbbbbb  

eno2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x9c900000-9c9fffff
```

netplan --debug apply:

```
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: starting new processing pass
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: starting new processing pass
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: eno2: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: Configuration is valid
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: eno1: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: Configuration is valid
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: Generating output files..
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: openvswitch: definition eno1 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: NetworkManager: definition eno1 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: openvswitch: definition eno2 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:169153): DEBUG: 09:57:10.149: NetworkManager: definition eno2 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, reloading networkd
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.520: starting new processing pass
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.520: starting new processing pass
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.520: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.520: eno2: setting default backend to 1
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.520: Configuration is valid
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.520: eno1: setting default backend to 1
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.520: Configuration is valid
DEBUG:Merged config:
b''
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.527: starting new processing pass
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.527: starting new processing pass
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.527: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.527: eno2: setting default backend to 1
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.527: Configuration is valid
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.527: eno1: setting default backend to 1
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.527: Configuration is valid
DEBUG:Merged config:
b''
DEBUG:Link changes: {}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for eno3
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for eno4
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for eno5
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for eno6
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for eno1
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for eno2
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: starting new processing pass
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: starting new processing pass
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: eno2: setting default backend to 1
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: Configuration is valid
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: eno1: setting default backend to 1
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: Configuration is valid
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: starting new processing pass
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: starting new processing pass
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: eno2: setting default backend to 1
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: Configuration is valid
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: eno1: setting default backend to 1
** (process:169151): DEBUG: 09:57:14.673: Configuration is valid
DEBUG:Merged config:
b''
```

***NOTE***: When I run `ip addr add 192.168.0.10/24 dev eno2` it works and I have an IP (pingable) on eno2. But I wish to have it with netplan.

Comment: maybe `ignore-carrier` as described at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697946/561090

Comment: Yes!! it works. Thank you!